# Postgresql join on jsonb array

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, jsonb-array-elements

I'm new to JSONB and I am wondering, if the following would be possible with a single query:

I have a lot of tables that look like this:

```
ID (INT)  |  members (JSONB)
```

all the tables has only one row.

example for 2 tables

**table1**:

*id*: 1

*data*:

```json
[
  {
    "computer": "12.12.12.12",
    "tag": "dog"
  },
  {
    "computer": "1.1.1.1",
    "tag": "cat"
  },
  {
    "computer": "2.2.2.2",
    "tag": "cow"
  }
]
```

**table2**:

*id*: 1

*data*:

```json
[
  {
    "IP address": "12.12.12.12",
    "name": "Beni",
    "address": "Rome"
  },
  {
    "IP address": "1.1.1.1",
    "name": "Jone",
    "address": "Madrid"
  }
]
```

The result should be rows like this :

| computer | tag | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12.12.12.12 | dog | Beni |
| 1.1.1.1 | cat | Jone |

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get values out of a jsonb array of objects you somehow have to explode them.
another way with jsonb_array_elements:

```
with _m as (
select
jsonb_array_elements(members.data) as data
from members
),
_m2 as (
select
jsonb_array_elements(members2.data) as data
from members2
)

select
_m.data->>'computer' as computer,
_m.data->>'tag' as tag,
_m2.data->>'name' as name
from _m
left join _m2 on _m2.data->>'IP address' = _m.data->>'computer'
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/68iC5TzLKbzkLZ8gFWYiLz/0

Answer (score 2):

Convert jsons into `setof` types using [jsonb_to_recordset function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) and then join them (like they were relational tables).

```sql
with table1 (id,members) as (
  values (1,'[{"computer": "12.12.12.12","tag": "dog"},{"computer": "1.1.1.1","tag": "cat"},{"computer": "2.2.2.2","tag": "cow"}]'::jsonb)
),   table2 (id,members) as (
  values (1,'[{"IP address": "12.12.12.12","name": "Beni", "address": "Rome"},{"IP address": "1.1.1.1","name": "Jone", "address": "Madrid"}]'::jsonb)
)
select t1.computer, t1.tag, t2.name
from jsonb_to_recordset((select members from table1 where id=1)) as t1(computer text,tag text)
join jsonb_to_recordset((select members from table2 where id=1)) as t2("IP address" text,name text)
  on t1.computer = t2."IP address"
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b75832ee74e3144cc9d321defbebb734)